# Air: Write to application storage directory during installation?

Tags: html, ajax, air, adobe

I'm writing an Adobe Air HTML app. I want to write to the application storage directory during installation, and thought you could point me in the right direction.

I've got a set of example "profiles" (text files) to include with our application. I would like to put the examples into Application Storage (or Document Storage), since the user is free to delete them, modify them, etc. Also, I don't want to re-write the files during Updates, only an initial installation.

But as far as I can figure out, the installer only writes to the application directory. Is there a simple command line change to ADT to send files to the application storage directory?

Here's my thought so far for a workaround:

1. Include the files in the application directory "Examples"
2. On startup, check if the "Examples" folder is in the Application Storage/Document Storage directory
3. If it doesn't exist, copy app:/Examples folder into the Application Storage/Document storage directory

But it would be a lot easier if this was part of the installer. Let me know if any other information would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to customize the normal AIR installer. Your workaround is the way to do it.